# How can i write if(KSO<20) then do a procedure in prolog?

Tags: syntax, prolog

I want to write:

```
 if (KSO<20) then {
                   printf( "Is there NO3 in the water (yes/no)");
                   scanf("%s",NUMKSOVALUE_value);
                   }
```

in prolog.
By now i have written :

```
 write('Is there NO3 in the water (yes/no)?'),
            nl, read(NUMKSOVALUE_value),
            member(NUMKSOVALUE_value,[yes,no]). :- (number(KSO_labvalue),KSO_labvalue < 20).
```

But it is not accepted. Can someone help me please with this?

Comment: `:-` is used to define a predicate clause. It separates the head of the predicate from the body. You have used it in some unusual way. Have you read any Prolog tutorials or have a Prolog book to learn some basic Prolog from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good place to start learning Prolog is: http://www.learnprolognow.org/

For your question, the following code will help get you started:

```
no3_present_in_water :-
    write('Enter KSO value:'), nl,
    read(V),
    process_response(V,Outcome),
    write('NO3 present: '), write(Outcome), nl.

process_response(A,B) :-
        A =< 20,
        B = 'no'.
process_response(A,B) :-
        A > 20,
        B = 'yes'.
```

Test:

```
?- no3_present_in_water.
Enter KSO value:
|: 10.
NO3 present: no
yes

?- no3_present_in_water.
Enter KSO value:
|: 30.
NO3 present: yes
yes
```